# How to insert multiple datasets (at once) in mysql with different values given?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a database with an api that gets change-information from a mobile app that works offline. So when the app synchronizes it provides lot of changed data. For many reasons we decided, that the app only send the changed data to the server, not the complete datase. (We dont want to overwrite changes of other users in different attributes).

```
create table Test(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title1 varchar(100), title2 varchar(100)); 
INSERT INTO Test (id,title1,title2) VALUES  (1,"A","B"), (2,"C","D");
```

Now I get a set of changes (many 1000) but they only give me the changed values.
So I get e.g.

```
(1,"A", <missing>),
(2, <missing> ,"D")
```

Is there a possiblity to insert them over

```
INSERT INTO Test (id,title1,title2) VALUES  (1,"A1", ), (2, ,"D1") ON
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title1=VALUES(title1), title2=(VALUES(title2);
```

Hope there is an answer for this.

Thanks a lot,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

Your api has to send something even it it's just null then you can test and set a column to itself if need be

```
drop table if exists t;
create table T(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title1 varchar(100), title2 varchar(100)); 
INSERT INTO T (id,title1,title2) VALUES  (1,"A","B"), (2,"C","D");

INSERT INTO T(id,title1,title2) VALUES  (1,"A1", null), (2, null,"D1") ON
DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE title1  = case when VALUES(title1) is not null then values(title1) else title1 end,
        title2 = case when VALUES(title2) is not null then values(title2) else title2 end;
```

Comment: Hi. 
Thanks for the first approach, but this is not possible.
What if the new value should be null?
I cannot decide between null and <should not be set>

Comment: And by the way you can write it shorter:

INSERT INTO T(id,title1,title2) VALUES  (1,"A1", null), (2, null,"D1") ON
DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE title1  = coalesce(VALUES(title1),title1),
      title2  = coalesce(VALUES(title2),title2);
        
select * from t;

Comment: 'What if the new value should be null?' - fair enough but if api cannot provide something then no chance..

Comment: Means I can only decide to manually do an update for each dataset or not be able to set any attribute to null?

Comment: `title1  = case when VALUES(title1) is not null then values(title1) else title1 end,` --> `COALESCE(VALUES(title1), title1)` .  (I have not tried this, but it seems like it would work and be simpler.)